# A finite abelian group has order $p^n$, where $p$ is prime, if and only if the order of every element of $G$ is a power of $p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Suppose that G is a finite Abelian group. Prove that G has order $p^n$, where p is prime, if and only if the order of every element of G is a power of p.

---

I tried the following route, but got stuck.  Using the fundamental theorem of finite Abelian groups, the problem reduces to proving Cauchy's theorem for a cyclic abelian group. If G is a cyclic group, and p divides G, then G has an element of order p whether p is prime or not. If we regard G as the integers mod p, then we can notice that if $|G| = kp$ then the integer k has order p in G.

Comment: Do you know the structure theorem for finite Abelian groups?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you prove at least one direction of implication?

Comment: The claim is true *also* without the "abelian" bit.

Comment: I tried the following route, but got stuck.  Using the fundamental theorem of finite Abelian groups. The problem reduces to proving Cauchy's theorem for a cyclic abelian group.
If G is a cyclic group, and p divides G, then G has an element of order p whether p is prime or not.
If we regard G as the integers mod p, then we can notice that if |G| = kp then the integer k has order p in G

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume $p$ divides the order, and $q$ is some other prime that also divides the order. By Cauchy's theorem there is an element of order $q$.

Therefore, if the order is not a power of a prime then all the elements can't be of order a power of the same prime.

Assume that the order of the group is $p^n$. Then the order of an element $a$ must divide the order.

Answer (score 1):

See: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/cauchyapp.pdf

To be exact, see theorem 1.1, it relies on Cauchy's Theorem. As already pointed out, the "abelian" part is not necessary.